# Referencing sp.js in html page gives error

Tags: javascript, app, sp.js

I have referenced sp.js in html page in my sp hosted add-in, in order to use client object model in javascript. But it's giving me an error on _spPageContextInfo while it's referencing the sp.js, why sp.js is referencing _spPageContextInfo?

In the chrome error message it says:

> Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException:
>   Cannot find current web URL information on the page.

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]
Error message taken from sp.js, and it gives an error when referencing `new SP.ClientContext()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I give you a example where you can view what are the files you need to use sp.js
http://todosharepoint.blogspot.com.ar/2014/08/que-librerias-necesitamos-para-poder.html